# Edge morphisms coincide cup-products in the Tate spectral sequence

Tags: spectral-sequences, galois-cohomology

In the Tate spectral sequence, the edge morphism coincides with the cup product.
The proof is written in Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg's book: Cohomology of Number Fields (Theorem 2.5.5,p125).
https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/NSW2.2.pdf

However I don't understand the proof.

In (p.126, line 5), "we obtain a commutative diagram", but 
no explanation about the commutativity is written. I think this is not obvious, and the commutativitiy should rather be the heart of the proof.
(In other words, line 9, why can the lower arrow be the evaluation map?)

It would be appreciated if you help me, explaining it or suggesting another book or article.

Comment: Let me explain what is the point: 

Edge morphisms are defined fiestly for general in page 99, and for Tate sequence in page 123.

Edge-morphisms are defined using kernels and images, but concering with what element is mapped from the given element, the morphisms are almost black-boxes at page 125.

This theorem 2.2.5 is the first theorem describing the deteiled innner information of the morphisms.

So, to show the connectivity i am asking, we have to know how the edge morphisms are defined. 

But the proof contains no such information.

Comment: typo: Line 4:2.2.5 => 2.5.5, Line -2:connectivity =>commutativity. Sorry.